# c# - Configure BsonSerializer to serialize any kind of class

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, .net-6.0, bson

## Main issue

I created a c# .NET 6 application to interact with a lot of DBs like MongoDB. It creates random types and objects with System.Reflection. When trying to call ToBsonDocument on these objects I either get
"Type Test is not configured as a type that is allowed to be serialized for this instance of ObjectSerializer."
or
"System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains more than one element" when adding this before calling Bson-specific serializations

```
var objectSerializer = new ObjectSerializer(type => ObjectSerializer.DefaultAllowedTypes(type) || type.Assembly.FullName.StartsWith("MyAssembly"));
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(objectSerializer);
```

which I don't understand as I am iterating over a List where objects type is Test.

## How I try to create BsonDocs from single objs

```
foreach (var obj in source)
{
      var document = obj.ToBsonDocument();
      documents.Add(document);
}
```

## How I create the types

```
var assemblyName = new AssemblyName("MyAssembly");
var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(typeName + "Module");
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(typeName, TypeAttributes.Public);


var type = typeBuilder.CreateType();
```

## How I add properties

```
var fieldBldrName = typeBuilder.DefineField(kvp.Key, kvp.Value, FieldAttributes.Public);
var propBldrName = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(kvp.Key, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault,
    kvp.Value, null);

var getSetAttr =
    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
    MethodAttributes.HideBySig;

var custNameGetPropMthdBldr =
    typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"get_{kvp.Key}",
        getSetAttr,
        kvp.Value,
        Type.EmptyTypes);

var custNameGetIL = custNameGetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBldrName);
custNameGetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

var custNameSetPropMthdBldr =
    typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"set_{kvp.Key}",
        getSetAttr,
        null,
        new Type[] { kvp.Value });

var custNameSetIL = custNameSetPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBldrName);
custNameSetIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Last, we must map the two methods created above to our PropertyBuilder to
// their corresponding behaviors, "get" and "set" respectively.
propBldrName.SetGetMethod(custNameGetPropMthdBldr);
propBldrName.SetSetMethod(custNameSetPropMthdBldr);
```

Comment: It seems like you're dynamically creating types and then trying to serialize them to BSON using the MongoDB C# driver. The MongoDB C# driver uses reflection to determine how to serialize and deserialize types, and it caches this information. When you're dynamically creating types, the driver might not be aware of them, leading to the serialization issues you're seeing. Instead of dynamically creating types, if possible, consider using a more straightforward approach like using BsonDocument directly or using a dictionary. You can avoid the complexities of dynamic type creation & serialization.

Comment: At first thanks for the reply. 
As I also connected DBMS like MS SQL Server, InfluxDB and Apache Solr it will be hard to work with BsonDocuments all over the application. If its not possible to handle those "runtime types" I really woudl have to switch to Dictionaries, but this is not the best solution for me as I have to handle two dictionaries with property names, property types and property values for every object running through the system.
My goal is to benchmark those DBMS by measuring and benchmark the code.